# Facebook Page Tab App with user_likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm developing the following "Page Tab" facebook app with the following scenario:

1. if the visitors already liked the page, i will show him an image thanks him
2. else i will show an image that require him to like the page to enter the contest.

I'm the developer of the app and i'm using "user_likes" to get if he liked the page or not.
But its only worked fine in my account others are not working and always give result as he not liked the page>

Please advise.

Regards,
Moayyad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook "fan gate" with C#/asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475887/facebook-fan-gate-with-c-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the today's 5th question about the same topic I think. Why can't you use the search of StackOverflow, or even Google? There are lot's of similar questions including valid answers already, for example here: [perl Facebook::Graph API check if user likes page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730048/perl-facebookgraph-api-check-if-user-likes-page/23731187#23731187)